# Fill missing months

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and I need to fill the missing values by looking at other table.

[image]

**Date Table**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:** - I did cross join but not sure how to fill it with 0 values

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM PRODUCTS a 
  JOIN "DATE" b
    ON a.YEAR=b.YEAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT pc.*, d.*,
       COALESCE(p.revenue, 0) as revenue,
       . . . 
FROM DATE d CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT product_group, customer FROM PRODUCTS p) pc LEFT JOIN
     PRODUCTS p
     ON p.YEAR = d.YEAR AND p.MONTH = d.MONTH AND
        p.product_group = pc.product_group AND p.customer = pc.customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Partition outer join is handy for such things:

```
select product_group, customer, d.year, d.month, nvl(p.revenue, 0) as rev, nvl(p.sales, 0) as sls
  from date_tbl d 
  left join products p partition by (product_group, customer) 
    on p.year = d.year and p.month = d.month
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=52b2f61b29db731295d6179607759117)</sup>**